# Setting value of dojo datetimepicker

Tags: dojo, struts2

I want to set the value of datetimepicker tag through code please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP:

```
<s:datetimepicker name="date" ... />
```

Action from which the JSP is generated (NOT THE FORM ACTION):

```
public Date getDate() {
        return ...
    }
```